# Pre-Image of Generated Sigma-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

There is very well known lemma:
Let $\mathit f$: $X \mapsto Y $ be a mapping.

Let $\mathcal G \subseteq \mathcal P(Y)$ be a collection of subsets of $Y$. 
$\\$

then $\mathit f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal G)) = \sigma(\mathit f^{-1}(\mathcal G))$. $\\$

I do not understand this lemma. The domain of the function $\mathit f$ is $X$, and the codomain is $Y$. $\\$

Thus, the domain of the function $\mathit f^{-1}$ is $Y$, not $2^{Y}$. The function $\mathit f$ is just not defined on $2^{Y}$. But obviously the elements of $\mathcal G$ and $\sigma(\mathcal G)$ consist of the elements of $2^{Y}$?
Where is the mistake in my arguments? $\\$

E.g.

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\ 
4 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
\begin{matrix}
\to \\
\to \\
\to \\ 
\to \\
\end{matrix} 
\left(\begin{matrix}
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\ 
8 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

But this mapping is not defined on e.g. {5,7}, which is a subset of $2^{Y}$.

Comment: It’s simply notation. By $f^{-1}(G)$ we mean the set of preimages $f^{-1}(G)$ for all $G$ in $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: I did not get it.  $\mathit f^{-1}$ is defined on $2^{Y}$? Do you mean that the domain of $\mathit f$   
 is $2^X$ and the codomain is $2^Y$? May be you meant to write $\mathit f^{-1}(\mathcal G)$, not $\mathit f^{-1}(G)$? In any case you provided no definition of notation which I suppose I do not inderstand.

Comment: For $G \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(G) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in G\}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand the definition of  $\mathit f^{-1}(G)$. But the lemma is about $\mathit f^{-1}(\mathcal G)$, not about $\mathit f^{-1}(G)$.
If $\mathcal G=\{\{5,7\},\{5\}\}$ in my example, what is $\mathit f^{-1}(\mathcal G)$?

Comment: @snar here is the link of the lemma https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pre-Image_Sigma-Algebra_of_Generated_Sigma-Algebra

Answer (score 2):

OP agrees that $f^{-1}(G) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in G\}$ for $G \subset Y$, and the definition of $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$ was given in words in the comments as "the set of preimages $f^{-1}(G)$ for all $G \in \mathcal{G} $ ". Written verbatim, $$f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) = \{f^{-1}(G) : G \in \mathcal{G}\} \subset \mathcal{P}(X).$$  The first step of the linked proof, $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) \subset f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G}))$ is spelled out as 
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) &= \{f^{-1}(G) : G \in \mathcal{G}\} \\
&\subset \{f^{-1}(G) : G \in \sigma(\mathcal{G})\} \\
&= f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{G})).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!